# prime numbers. show that $p_{n+1} \le {p_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_n +1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ be the n-th prime number.

show that $p_{n+1} \le {p_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_n +1}$

I´ve used a few primes and obtained the same result, even when this assumption seems trivial I have no idea how to prove this for the n-th prime.

I'd appreciate some help

Comment: Examine the prime factors of the integer $p_1\ldots p_n + 1$. What could they be, or rather what couldn't they be ?

Comment: Hint: Prove that every positive integer other than $1$ has a prime factor. Can any of $p_1,\dots,p_n$ be prime factors of $p_1\cdots p_n+1$?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was very easy, I´m sorry for not seeing it...

Comment: There is a much stroger inequality, [Bonse's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonse%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic we know that the number $r = p_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_n +1$ also has a prime decomposition. None of the primes $p_1,\dots,p_n$ can be a divisor of $r$ though, as $r = 1 \text{ mod  }p$. Therefore some other prime $p_s$, $s \geq n+1$, needs to be a divisor of $r$, such that we get that $p_{n+1} \leq p_s$ and $p_s \leq r$ since $p_s$ is a divisor of $r$. Thus we have $p_{n+1} \leq r$

In case that you don't know the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, try to prove it with the following hint:

You can get the existence via induction and the uniqueness by using Euclid's Lemma (if a prime divides a product then also one of the two factors).

Comment: This answer overlooks the possibility that $p_1\cdot \dots \cdot p_n+1$ is a prime and has no decomposition. That would open the door the claim that $p_{n+1}=p_1\cdot \dots \cdot p_n+1$. That possibility, however, is rendered impossible by consideration of the number $p_1\cdot \dots \cdot p_n-1$, which, whether it is prime or is decomposable, points to the existence of primes that are both larger than $p_n$ but smaller than $p_1\cdot \dots \cdot p_n+1$.

Comment: That case is not overlooked. The prime decomposition of a prime is the prime itself. Therefore, if $r = p_s$ is a prime, we trivially get that none of the primes $p_1,\dots,p_n$ is a divisor (or by my argument above), such that $s \geq n + 1$ etc.